# How to mimic the functionality of the "Add Product" button in within the Product Related list in Opportunity?

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, related-list, opportunity-lineitem

I need to mimic the functionality of the "Add Product" button that is shown on the Product Related List within Opportunity.
[image: The button I need to add]

And I need to add it to a related list for my Custom Packages Object
[image: Where the button needs to go]

I was hoping that this could be found within options for the relationship, or within the settings for the related list, but I've had no such luck.

I would need to know: Can this be done with standard functionality? If so, how? Or does this need to be coded in some way? If it does, are there any examples out there I can learn to make that functionality from?

Comment: you need vf for this .no escape ;(

Comment: And I'm okay with that, but I'm a bit new to this whole system. Are there any example's you know of for this sort of thing?

Comment: Have added my response .You can use that or have a developer starting from the blog link shared

Comment: I don't think there any step by step guide for what you are asking. It's a bit of development you have to do there. I will just point out what you need to do, first create a custom button on you custom object. That button will point to a VisualForce page, which will pass the Id of the package as part of the redirect. That VisualForce page will have a controller which will potentially do a select or a search using a SOQL/SOSL query. You need a relationship between Packages and Products. Search on google the various keywords like VisualForce, Controller, Custom button.Post again if you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

There is a product screen thats been built .

http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU

This screen is unmanaged package and code can be customized to meet your need .

This should be great starting point .